# Angular: How to mutate a core module service in a lazy loaded module?

Tags: angular, angular6

Imagine you create a service in your core module that looks like this:

```
export interface Content {
  name: string;
  content: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class ContentService {
  contents: Array<Content> = [];

   getContent(name: string) {
     return this.contents.filter(content => content.name === name)[0];   
   }
}
```

The idea being that you will have *multiple* lazy loaded modules and in each module a component will call this service singleton, pass in its module's name, and get its related content.

Now, you could add all the `Content` objects in a factory for this service in core module, or app module, but is there a way to mutate the `ContentService` singleton *in each lazy loaded module* and add that module's content object?

You could alter the singleton in a component in the lazy loaded module but I'm looking to do it at the module level or perhaps in some kind of event listener in module loading.

Comment: Have you considered using a provider or Ngrx effects? I've used the Effect method on lazy-loaded modules in the past. Ngrx is heavy, but does make some things very easy.